# Time series forecasting use SVM

Tags: python, time-series

I am trying to set-up a python code for forecasting a time-series, using SVM libraries of scikit-learn.

My data consists of X values at a day interval for the last one years, and I need to predict y for a month of the next year . Here's what I have set up -

```
SVR().fit(X, y).predict(X)
```

But for this prediction to work, I need the X value for the next  month, which is not available. How do I set this up to predict future y values?

Comment: You probably need to set up a loop and predict the values one at a time.

Comment: @gordon-linoff, i would appreciate if you could help me with this my dear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350460/python-time-series-prediction-of-future-events-using-svr-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `(X,y)` is your train set (356 data instances with their labels), to forecast the first month of the next year your SVR Model need a data set `X_nextMonth` (30 data instances with the same features as those of `X`) to pass as argument to its `.predict()` method that he can predict labels `y_nextMonth`.

Comment: so X is just datetime such as 20140101?

Comment: It depends on your data, can you give as a sample of your it?

Comment: mfd_date    
20130701
20130702
20130703
20130704
20130705
20130706
20130707                        mfd_daily_yield
1.5787
1.5461
1.467
1.4223
1.3845
1.3674                          mfd_7daily_yield
6.307
6.174
6.034
5.903
5.739
5.582

Comment: Sorry for disappointing you but as you have just one qualitative feature SVR couldn't help you even if it gives a result but that will be very week as a prediction.

Comment: one qualitative feature refers to datetime?

Comment: yes, to have a good SVR model you must have one or more quantitative feature

Comment: can u tell me the differences of  the input vector X between time-series prediction and standard kernelized regression problem?

Comment: @farhawa, I would appreciate if you could help me with this dear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357805/prediction-time-series-prediction-of-future-events-using-svr-module