# Prediction: Time-series prediction of future events using SVR module

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series

I want to perform time-series prediction of future events using SVR module from scikit-learn. Here is my source code I am trying to work with:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.switch_backend('newbackend')

seq_num=[]
win=[]

def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFileReader) # skipping column names
        for row in csvFileReader:
            seq_num.append(int(row[0])
            win.append(int(row[6]))
    return

def predict_win(X, y, x):
    win = np.reshape(X,(len(X), 1)) 

    svr_lin = SVR(kernel= 'linear', C= 1e3)
    svr_poly = SVR(kernel= 'poly', C= 1e3, degree= 2)
    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel= 'rbf', C= 1e3, gamma= 0.1) 
    svr_rbf.fit(X, y) 
    svr_lin.fit(X, y)
    svr_poly.fit(X, y)

    plt.scatter(X, y, color= 'black', label= 'Data') 
    plt.plot(y, svr_rbf.predict(X), color= 'red', label= 'RBF model') 
    plt.plot(y,svr_lin.predict(X), color= 'green', label= 'Linear model') 
    plt.plot(y,svr_poly.predict(X), color= 'blue', label= 'Polynomial model') 
    plt.xlabel('X, other features')
    plt.ylabel('win')
    plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0], svr_lin.predict(x)[0], svr_poly.predict(x)[0]

get_data('net_data.csv') 


predicted_win = predict_win(X, y, 29)
```

My dataset is very huge and so a portion of my csv dataset is included at the end. I am interested in the 7th column. I wanted to predict when the values in the 7th column increase or when it decreases. Is it possible to look into the 7th column ONLY and do the time-series prediction?  Any help with this would be so much appreciated? Thanks!

```
0.007804347,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3796291040,3796277984,10,2147483647,28960,3034,29312
0.007856739,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3796293936,3796278008,11,2147483647,29056,2999,29312
0.010605189,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3796320000,3796291040,20,2147483647,55040,2969,29312
0.010850907,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3796348960,3796305520,30,2147483647,84096,2946,29312
0.013598458,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3796377920,3796320000,40,2147483647,113024,2951,29312
0.01368011,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3796434392,3796348960,60,2147483647,170880,2956,29312
0.015104265,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3796434392,3796363440,70,2147483647,199936,2940,29312
0.016406964,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3796490864,3796377920,80,2147483647,220160,2943,29312
0.016465876,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3796537200,3796432944,81,80,330240,2925,29312
0.018355321,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3796547336,3796434392,81,80,333056,2914,29312
0.020171945,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3796603808,3796490864,83,80,382336,2956,29312
0.237314523,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3810417728,3809658976,529,396,1775360,7109,29312
0.237409075,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,44,3810417728,3809700968,530,397,1859328,7381,29312
0.237486647,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,44,3810417728,3809700968,371,371,1960704,7365,29312
0.237807596,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,44,3810417728,3809700968,371,371,1980928,7362,29312
0.237989588,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,44,3810417728,3809700968,371,371,1989632,7400,29312
0.259123971,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3811590608,3811251776,261,260,2267648,5885,29312
0.259174008,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3811655768,3811289424,261,260,2267648,5918,29312
0.262546461,10.0.0.11:49438,10.0.12.12:5001,32,3811720928,3811354584,261,260,2267648,5823,29312
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the svm function below has a problem:

The second line, `win = ...` is unused, and will cause an error.  Delete it.

```
def predict_win(X, y, x):
    win = np.reshape(X,(len(X), 1))  # <----This line

    svr_lin = SVR(kernel= 'linear', C= 1e3)
    svr_poly = SVR(kernel= 'poly', C= 1e3, degree= 2)
    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel= 'rbf', C= 1e3, gamma= 0.1) 
    svr_rbf.fit(X, y) 
    svr_lin.fit(X, y)
    svr_poly.fit(X, y)

    plt.scatter(X, y, color= 'black', label= 'Data') 
    plt.plot(y, svr_rbf.predict(X), color= 'red', label= 'RBF model') 
    plt.plot(y,svr_lin.predict(X), color= 'green', label= 'Linear model') 
    plt.plot(y,svr_poly.predict(X), color= 'blue', label= 'Polynomial model') 
    plt.xlabel('X, other features')
    plt.ylabel('win')
    plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0], svr_lin.predict(x)[0], svr_poly.predict(x)[0]
```

---

Second, I don't know why there is an entire function for reading a csv.  Ignore it and use pandas. Here is a sample code that will work:

```
from sklearn import svm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def predict_win(X,y,x):
    svr_lin = svm.SVR(kernel='linear',C=1e3)
    svr_poly = svm.SVR(kernel='poly',C=1e3, degree=2)
    svr_rbf = svm.SVR(kernel='rbf',C=1e3,gamma=0.1)
    svr_rbf.fit(X,y)
    svr_lin.fit(X,y)
    svr_poly.fit(X,y)

    plt.plot(y,svr_rbf.predict(X),color='red',label='RBF model')
    plt.plot(y,svr_lin.predict(X),color='green',label='Linear model')
    plt.plot(y,svr_poly.predict(X),color='blue', label='Polynomial model')
    plt.xlabel('X, other features')
    plt.ylabel('win')
    plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    return [svr_rbf.predict(x)[0],svr_lin.predict(x)[0],svr_poly.predict(x)[0]]

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

data_np_array = df.values

y = np.ndarray.copy(data_np_array[:,6])
Xleft = np.ndarray.copy(data_np_array[:,:6])
Xright = np.ndarray.copy(data_np_array[:,7:])
X = np.hstack((Xleft,Xright))

x0 = np.ndarray.copy(X[0,:])
xp = predict_win(X,y,x0)

percent_off = [min(data_np_array[0,2],prediction)/max(data_np_array[0,2],prediction) for prediction in xp]
```

---

The intermediate steps, where you clean up the imported data, turn it from a dataframe to a numpy array, copy your 7th column as the regression to fit, delete it from your training data, and rebuild a new array must be done before fitting to the SVR.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

data_np_array = df.values

y = np.ndarray.copy(data_np_array[:,6])
Xleft = np.ndarray.copy(data_np_array[:,:6])
Xright = np.ndarray.copy(data_np_array[:,7:])
X = np.hstack((Xleft,Xright))
```

Let me know if these worked.  I just took a few lines from your data table above.

Comment: @Mahsolid Ah, then maybe you just have to do array copies. I'll add that in the answer. Let me know if that doesn't work, and I'll test run the code.  If I can't get the same error, you can send me the csv, but I should be able to get it working.

Comment: @mahsolid Ok, copied over the code and tested it.  Looks like there were a few problems with your original function.  I don't know why your source is using a wrapper for the CSV reader--use pandas dataframe.  This should work, let me know.

Comment: you are right - the old error is gone now but there is this new error related to data type conversion: `array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '10.0.12.12:5001'`. The contents of the second and third column are NOT numeric.

Comment: @Mahsolid Oh, yeah, you have to either remove those columns or convert them to a number.  I would remove them if I were you, since they are dates.

Comment: @Mahsolid ah, yeah, then I would say they are even less relevant to prediction--will only confuse everything when you add new data, because an IP address has nothing to do with anything, are non random, and never repeat--you might never see a situation with the same ip address in a non-training prediction, depending on your problem.  Was thinking that if you were doing sports, date could be relevant.

Comment: you are completely right my dear. I just removed them and it compiled without error. Now running it but it seems to take a while since the CSV file is relatively big. Thank you so very much once again. You are just awesome! I have marked your answer as an accepted answer!!!

Comment: do you think this warning will have an impact in the prediction result dear? `DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)`

Comment: @Mahsolid no, but it will cause your code to break in probably something like 6 months when you update your libraries.  For your code, you would want to do x.reshape(1,-1) for the second x (the lower case x) in the prediction function.

Comment: yeah right, i fixed it as `x=x.reshape(1,-1)`. Thanks!

Comment: @Mahsolid Np...Good luck!

Comment: I run it with a sample data and got this graph my dear but the plot seems hard to interpret it (like when it increases and decreases). Do you think something is wrong the plotting function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529975/support-vector-regression-prediction-graph

Comment: it seems you are busy dear.